# At the time of the exception, the container was:

Tags: exception, stack, was

A customer gave me this Error log, he told me that he isn't able to read his email-history in our software.

What I can find in the error logs is the following:

```
At the time of the exception, the container was:                    

  Resolving Comp.Shared.Mail.Mail,(none) (mapped from Comp.Shared.Mail.IMail, (none))                   
  Calling constructor Comp.Shared.Mail.Mail()                   

Stack Trace:    at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.DoBuildUp(Type t, Object existing, String name, IEnumerable`1 resolverOverrides)                    
   at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.DoBuildUp(Type t, String name, IEnumerable`1 resolverOverrides)                  
   at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainerExtensions.Resolve[T](IUnityContainer container, ResolverOverride[] overrides)                    
   at Comp.DCMS.BLL.LettersManager.GetMergedEmailByID(Int32 emailID)                    
   at Comp.DCMS.WCFServices.LettersService.GetMergedEmailByID(Int32 emailID)
```

I've replaced our Company name with "Comp" if anybody could help me, it would be great.
Thanks! kind regards.

Comment: Please edit title of question to make it meaningful. And what is `our software` ? If you don't give enough info, that question might be useless.

Comment: I don't really know what I should name the title. We have creditmanagement software, in order to keep track of invoices etc. In our software you can click on "History" tab to see the Mails that have been send in the past. Though when you click on the mail to open it, this error pops-up. Also, when you view letters in History, it gives the same error. The part above is what I could find in the logs, that makes sense to me.

Comment: I'm afraid this is off topic, please read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic , and see if you can edit your question so that it does fit.